# Help! TinyMCE is reformatting my code!

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

when i edit the HTML source from:

```
<div />
```

the result is always something like:

```
<div></div>
```

i don't want that.. it should leave my code alone ;)

here is the config:

```
tinyMCE.init({
// General options
mode : "textareas",
theme: "advanced",
element_format : "xhtml",
    remove_linebreaks: false,
    remove_redundant_brs: false,
    cleanup_on_startup : false,
    cleanup: false, // cleanup: true -> custom_elemts are not working...
    verify_html : false,
    forced_root_block: false,
    apply_source_formatting: false,
    fix_nesting: false,
    fix_table_elements: false,
    fix_list_elements : false,
    fix_content_duplication : false,
    preformatted : false,

    extended_valid_elements: "pbo:*[*]",

});
```

any ideas?

Comment: The stuff mentioned above is just an example.. this happens to all the other elements too... with the element_format = xhtml TinyMCE produces strange behaviours...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're specifying the format as `xhtml` and `div`s cannot be self-closing -- that's why it's fixing it for you. If you want it to be exactly as you say then you'll need to change the `element_format` property.

Comment: `<div />` is valid in XHTML. You shouldn't use it because it messes up in IE.

Comment: @Tim: [citation needed] :), `<div />` is definitely valid _XML_, but everything I've ever come across says `div`s are not self-closing elements. `script` is another good example. I could be wrong on this, for sure. However, as you pointed, out IE explodes when given self-closing divs, so the answer still remains -- stay away :)

Answer (score 3):

You really really don't want `<div />` tags. They are not valid HTML (and IE always parses documents as HTML) and [will break DOM traversal methods in IE](http://www.thismuchiknow.co.uk/?p=184).